# Does SwampDragon do async database calls?

Tags: django, tornado, swampdragon

[SwampDragon](http://swampdragon.net/) seems like a nice library, tightly coupled with Django. Uses Tornado's `ioloop` to handle websockets.

But does it do async database queries, or sync (blocking) queries? Postgres or MySQL. How would one go about handling computationally intensive websocket "request" (message from client) without blocking the event loop? Or is that automagically handled by Tornado?

Answer (score 0):

I used SwampDragon to send client notifications, and I do queries to DB I've combined SD with [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to do the async work. Maybe you could try it. Good Luck.